# Joi validation error from which field to show error next to it in UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi

I have to use Joi validation library to validate in the API input and so send the output.

I have say created a schema as follows:

```
import Joi from '@hapi/joi'

const eventSchema = Joi.object({
  title: Joi.string()
    .min(7)
    .max(50)
    .required()
    .error(() => Error('Event title has to be least 7 and max 50 characters.')),

  description: Joi.string()
    .min(10)
    .max(400)
    .required()
    .error(() => Error('Event description has to be least 10 and max 400 characters.')),

  place: Joi.string()
    .min(6)
    .max(40)
    .required()
    .error(() => Error('Event place has to be least 6 and max 40 characters.'))
})
export default eventSchema
```

When I validate this, I get validation error as expected. The problem here is I do not know which field really caused error. I wanted to know this because I want exactly to show the error next to that field which caused the error instead of just generic validation message showing at the top of form.

```
const isValid = eventSchema.validate()

if (isValid.error) {
  const fieldNameWhichCauseError = ???

  return {
   errors: { [fieldNameWhichCauseError]: isValid.error.message }
  }
}

// Everything looks good save to db
// ...etc.
```

The above code has now way to know the field name in **fieldNameWhichCauseError = ???**. Can somebody please help me? I haven't seen anyone doing such scenario. I also didn't find in the docs. I have so many schemas and validations in place and this is something really blocking me to show the error at proper place in the UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Someday it might help someone searching here.

First I would create a custom ValidationError object.

```
class ValidationError extends Error {
   constructor(message, fieldName) {
     super(message)
     this.fieldName = fieldName
   }
}
```

Now use this class in the above code posted in Question. Use ValidationError instead of Error class and also pass the field name to it. Example

```
const eventSchema = Joi.object({
  title: Joi.string()
    .min(7)
    .max(50)
    .required()
    .error(() => new ValidationError('Event title has to be least 7 and max 50 characters.', 'title'))
})
```

Remember to use **new** while using custom class. The code which validates can get `error.fieldName` value from the error object passed down.

I hope this is the correct approach. If there is better approach, please post I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

On **Joi 17.4**, the `error` returned by [validate()](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.2#validationerror) has a property called `details`, from which you can access the details about those errors (like which fields those errors belong to).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way to achieve this as throwing error is not recommended way to achieve this. (https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyerrorerr)

You should leverage `any.messages` (https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anymessagesmessages) and add your custom messages. The way you are defining them, you always get same type of error message even if user hasn't specified any thing. Also using error overrides `abortEarly` options. That means you will not get all the messages, just the first one.

Using messages can be done like this.

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');
const eventSchema = Joi.object({
    title: Joi.string()
        .min(7)
        .max(50)
        .required()
        .messages({
            'string.base': `"description" should be a type of 'text'`,
            'string.min': '"title" has to be least {#limit} characters.',
            'string.max': '"title" has to be max {#limit} characters.',
            'any.required': `"title" is a required field`,
        }),

    description: Joi.string()
        .min(10)
        .max(400)
        .required()
        .messages({
            'string.base': `"description" should be a type of 'text'`,
            'string.min': '"description" has to be least {#limit} characters.',
            'string.max': '"description" has to be max {#limit} characters.',
            'any.required': `"description" is a required field`
        }),

    place: Joi.string()
        .min(6)
        .max(40)
        .required()
        .messages({
            'string.base': `"place" should be a type of 'text'`,
            'string.min': '"place" has to be least {#limit} characters.',
            'string.max': '"place" has to be max {#limit} characters.',
            'any.required': `"place" is a required field`
        })
});

eventSchema.validate({
    "title": "hi"
}, {
    "abortEarly": false
});
```

Comment: That is good suggestion.You see it still doesn't give answer to which field caused the error, so in a way I would be still stuck with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
import Joi from "joi";

const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {

    if (err instanceof Joi.ValidationError) {
       // validation error
    }
    
    // another error
}
```